# How to iterate through alphanumeric characters for a string of 2 characters

Tags: c, unix, encryption

I have to iterate through all alphanumeric characters, including lower case and upper case and numbers and for each one, I have to call the crypt command.

So, I have to check for Aa, aA, 1a, a1, 1A, A1 etc till all possible combinations and call crypt KEY  crypt_file.

Is there an efficient way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: this site offers help to people that are programming and get stuck. Show us what you have tried so far. You should also try to make your question clearer, 'I have to check for ...' ?? check what? Sample input, expected output, actual output and code make for a much better form a question that people can help with. Good luck.

Comment: You will need to give and example and be more specific about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the characters into an array. Something like:

```
const char vals[] = { '0', '1', '2', ..., 'a', 'b', ... 'Z' }; // Probably better to generate it programatically
```

A double "for" loop should do it:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < kNumVals; i++) // kNumVals is the number of characters in your array
{
    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < kNumVals; j++)
    {
        char myString[3] = {vals[i],vals[j],'\0'};
        // Do something with myString
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most efficient way would be generating once all the combinations and storing them in a file. Then just read the file, since the combinations will not change.

Answer (score 0):

Enter the list of characters in str , i.e. "aA1". This is to check for all possible combinations like aA1,1Aa etc.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<alloc.h>
#include<conio.h>


void swap(char*,int);
void gotoloop(char*,int);

void main()
{
char *ch;
int i,j,k,l;
ch=(char*)malloc(20);
//clrscr();
printf("Enter the string\n"); //Enter AAaa11 for your case
gets(ch);

l=strlen(ch);
gotoloop(ch,l);
//if flag !=false call encryption.
return;
}

void gotoloop(char *ch,int l)
{
int i,k;
k=l;

if(l<=1) 
return;


for(i=0;i<k;i++)
{
swap(ch,k);
l--;
gotoloop(ch,l);
l++;
if(k==2) {
 printf("\n%s ",ch);//check this from the list, if not found set FLAG=false
}
}

}


void swap(char *ch,int r)

{
char c;
int i;

c=ch[r-1];
for(i=r-1;i>0;i--)
ch[i]=ch[i-1];
ch[0]=c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using 62 characters: 0-9, A-Z, a-z  10 + 26 + 26 = 62.  You want all possible two character combinations from 00 to zz.  Think of them as two digit numbers in base 62:

```
 0 -> 00
 1 -> 01
10 -> 0A
61 -> 0z
62 -> 10
```

Go through all the numbers from 0 to 3843 (62^2 - 1) and convert them to a two digit number in base 62.